# Why is my VS Code text all the same color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Alright so, I'm new to coding and I got VS Code and for some reason, all my text is mostly the same color. At first when I open VS Code it looks like this:

[image: Image 1]

But, as soon as I type something it looks like this:

[image: Image 2]

It's kind of hard to see different variables or methods when it's all the same color. Any idea why it looks like that? Also, I'm not sure if it helps but I'm using unity as well.

Comment: You do have the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) installed, right?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yea, I have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that VS Code has problems communicating with Unity. Because all the Unity stuff is blue, the rest is colored as normal.
I would check if VS Code is set as editor. You can see it here: 
Edit -> Preferences -> External Tools -> External Script Editor 
Make sure VS Code is set there.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. When I got it I thought I had done that but I didn't.